# photoshop сохранить в jpeg (не jpg)

Tags: photoshop

как в photoshop сохранить изображение в `.jpeg` формате, что не делаю сохраняет в `.jpg`! а нужно именно в `.jpeg`

Comment: А ручками переименовать `.jpg` в `.jpeg`, не пробовали? ;)

Comment: @DmitriySimushev да вот что и бесит, постоянно ручками, неужели не может сразу сохранять как мне нужно?

Comment: `.jpeg` и `.jpg` -- по сути одно и то же.

Comment: @DmitriySimushev да, но для браузера это разные файлы...

Comment: А разве при "save for web" нет принудительной опции для расширения?

Answer (score 0):

Можно сохранять как обычно, с расширением jpg, а потом зайти в папку, вызвать в ней консоль (cmd) и написать `ren *.jpg *.jpeg`. Инструкция для винды, но думаю, что подобная команда есть и в любой другой ОС.